# How can I start Ubuntu after install was interrupted?

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth, avahi

I can get as far as choosing Ubuntu on the start like menu then it loads up a black screen.
Here is the screen that pops up:

```
[ OK ] Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
[ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
[ OK ] Started Getty on tty1.
[ OK ] Reached target Login Prompts.
       Starting Set console scheme...
[ OK ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[ OK ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
[ OK ] Started set console scheme.
[ OK ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[ OK ] Started System Logging Service.
[ OK ] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
[ OK ] Reached target Multi-User System.
[ OK ] Reached target Graphical Interface.
       Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
```

And then it stays there forever. I can't type anything. Although I can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> and it will stop that process and then go back into tty1.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can u try to open tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1,F2,...,F6), Login and try to run `sudo apt-get install -f` than, `sudo apt-get reboot`

Comment: Maybe this link can help since from my observations, you have boot issues.
Here is the [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73755/installation-of-ubuntu-system-update-was-interrupted-now-i-cannot-boot-please)

Comment: @Benny I ran sudo apt-get install -f and it all went through okay after I ran sudo dpkg --configure -a. Then I attempted to run sudo apt-get reboot and it said "E: Invalid operation reboot".

Comment: You can do: `/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot`

Comment: Maybe your $PATH is damaged and because this you cant login

Comment: Maybe you could just start over and install again, erasing the partially installed system ? If the installation was interrupted, lots of things will be broken.

Comment: Wow awesome, that last command did it. Will that be a permanent fix?
Also a window just poped up saying that is could not download flashplugin-installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) 
Install missing:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Or if your PATH is broken, so:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin/install -f
```

Now reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Or if your PATH is broken, so:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/reboot
```

Comment: Well it all seems to be running properly now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, please mark my answer as the correct.